# Why didn't Thanos and the Avengers go to the realm of Eternity instead?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-love-and-thunder

In *Thor: Love and Thunder* we get to know about the realm of Eternity and how it can grant one person a wish.

Why didn't Thanos nor the Avengers go there to make their wish instead of collecting all the Infinity Stones?

Comment: A) it was a legend that none of them had heard of or thought to be true (Thor didn't believe it existed in Love and Thunder if I remember correctly), B) it was pulled from the comics just for L&T. Sure, Ultron could've collected Infinity Stones to end the Avengers. But he didn't, because we were waiting for Thanos to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to *Thor: Love and Thunder*, the realm of Eternity can only be accessed by using the Bifrost to unlock the door.

Presumably Thanos was unaware of the existence of Eternity, or the Bifrost, or the fact that the Bifrost was the key to Eternity — when Heimdall summoned it right in front of him to send Hulk to earth, Thanos just killed him, instead of saying hey now, maybe Eternity’s an option after all.

With Heimdall gone, as far as we know there was no way to summon the Bifrost until Eitri made Stormbreaker. Thor was probably the best source the Avengers had for researching cosmic legends like Eternity, but thanks to his depression after killing Thanos, he wasn’t really in the headspace to go searching for alternative McGuffin-based solutions to the continuing absence of half the universe’s inhabitants.

Shame though — turns out his bottle-opener could have saved a bunch of Time Heist work, plus Natasha and Tony’s lives. Nice going, King of Thunder!

Comment: To be clear it could only be accessed via the Bifrost which, at the time, only Stormbreaker could summon. This is correct though, whether Thanos knows about Eternity or not doesn't really matter because as far as he's aware the Bifrost can't be summoned by the time of IW.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Ah right, it was a Bifrost thing? Gosh, Ebony Maw really shouldn’t have killed Heimdall eh 

Comment: Isn't it strange for something to exist and it's way to open can only be a thing that doesn't exist? This means whomever knowd about the existence of realm of eternity before storm breaker was created also know the a storm breaker is a thing, which is strange.

Comment: @Mocas turns out as TheLethalCarrot pointed out above, the realm of Eternity is opened by the Bifrost, rather than Stormbreaker specifically. It’s just that by the time of _Love and Thunder_, Stormbreaker is the only known way to summon the Bifrost.

Answer (score 7):

#### In-universe: They didn't know/believe in the myth

In *Thor: Love and Thunder*, multiple characters say things along the lines of "Eternity is just a myth, it doesn't exist". Obviously the belief in the myth by our heroes wasn't very strong. And Thanos is hardly expected to know some vague myth whispered amongst the gods for eons, much less act on it when something as concrete as the Infinity Stones exists for him to look for - **at least two of them came into direct contact with him** during his pre-*Infinity War* plots, for heaven's sake - and so Infinity Stones were used.

#### Out-of-universe: It wasn't the planned plot, and it was Thor-specific rather than Avengers

The myth of Eternity comes out of the Marvel comics, and was linked to Thor and the mythical. **It would hardly have made sense for Thanos to go looking for it**. If anything, Thor might have looked for it as a "side-quest" while the other Avengers were working on assembling, like his skinny-dip in Ultron. Also, the plot wasn't meant for Thanos: just like **Ultron didn't look for the 6 Infinity Stones to end the Avengers**, Thanos isn't going to look for Eternity to kill half the universe.

#### Marvel has to up the stakes to make the movies interesting, even if the worldbuilding they do makes previous plots or movies seem less interesting

On another note, after Thanos trying to end the universe with the all-capable Stones, things can feel pretty low-stakes, like Hawkeye trying to take down a small group of Russians alongside a teenage girl or Sam Wilson and Bucky Barnes trying to rebuild world borders on Earth. That's why we started getting things like Kang controlling free will itself, Doctor Strange's variants destroying whole universes, a narrowly avoided multiversal collapse through a forgetting spell, and now, a supernatural being that can grant you the ability to kill every elevated entity in existence. **Marvel has to make things high stakes.**

Comment: Part of the mythos of the Infinity Stones is that they were related to, and possibly created by, the four Cosmic Entities, among which Eternity was one. They were all depicted in the murals on Morag in the chamber of the Power stone.

Comment: In the MCU, the Infinity Stones just sort of appeared across the virgin universe.

Answer (score 1):

### Thanos may not have known of this lore

The revelation of a whole tier of gods (Zeus *et al*) and the power of Eternity are novel to *Thor: Love and Thunder* which suggests that this knowledge is very privileged and Thanos may never have found out about it.

### The Avengers never even considered this as an option

For similar reasons, what you suggest was not even put forward as an option for the Avengers in their bid to undo the consequences of [the 'snap'](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War).

As far as the Avengers were concerned, the only resources powerful enough to reverse the effect of the Infinity Stones were the Stones themselves, necessitating the [Time Heist](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Avengers:_Endgame).

### A wish is not a 'sure thing'

While a promised wish from Eternity would be a very powerful affordance, there is no guarantee that Thanos could use it to get what he wanted, the destruction of half of all life in the universe. There are always practical limits to any 'wish' arrangement, as Eternity could choose not to grant, or to reinterpret, any wish made. This is not Thanos's style - he does not ask, wish, or beg from higher powers - he **takes the power for himself**.

Zeus feared that Gorr would use the power of Eternity to gain access to the realm of the gods and kill them all. We will never know if this wish would have been granted, as Gorr (perhaps surprisingly) wishes for [something more precious to him](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Love_(Earth-199999)) to be restored.